# Error term for prime harmonic

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, computational-number-theory

What is known about the asymptotic behavior of
$$
f(x)=\sum_{p\le x}\frac1p-\log\log x-B_1?
$$

Of course by Mertens we know that $f(x)=o(1),$ but has more been proved (in terms of $O$ or $\Omega_\pm$, say)? A reference would be great.

Comment: Bach and Shallit include a list of many useful estimates, title is probably Algorithmic Number Theory.

Comment: there is also some two or three volume thing which is entirely identities and estimates in number theory. I borrowed one volume once but cannot remember author(s). Just a list of results with individual references.

Comment: @WillJagy: Mitrinović et. al.'s _Handbook of Number Theory_?

Comment: Could be. Having more than one author seems right, also the title is promising. Let me try a few pages online...

Comment: yes, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/180725/sum-over-primes-involving-divisor-function-variation-of-the-titchmarsh-divisor

Comment: Some related discussion is at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/95743/why-mertens-could-not-prove-the-prime-number-theorem .  Actually, I think from summation by parts that the error term should basically be the error term in the prime number theorem divided by x, thus $O(\exp( - c \log^{3/5} x / \log\log^{1/5} x ) )$ unconditionally, or $O( x^{-1/2} \log x )$ on RH (one may possibly be able to reduce the log factor a bit).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

["Mertens' Proof of Mertens' Theorem"](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504289) suggests that Mertens had an error term of $O\left(\frac1{\ln x}\right)$, though that's not tight; theorem 14 there offers an $O\left(\frac1{\ln^2x}\right)$ unconditional estimate and an $O(x^{-1/2}\ln x)$ estimate dependent on RH, with references to the original proofs.

Comment: $O(x^{-1/2} \ln x)$, that is?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Indeed.  ($x$ and $n$ are canonically interchangeable anyway, right? :-) )